# AzureFunctions as a WebApp guidance

Tags: azure, azure-functions

Azure functions are awesome. I'm looking for guidance/suggestions on best way to setup an Azure function handle multiple web pages like a webApp and/or host a webApp inside of an Azure function.

In an Amazon Lambda/AI.Gateway I can have the AI. gateway route multiple requests URL to the same lambda function but I don't see how to accomplish this with Azure functions.

Example if I have an azure function setup to: http://hostname/myfunc it be great if I could set it up so if a user entered http://hostname/myfunc/home my azure function would still be invoked and my function could handle based on its own routing logic.

I tried making multiple proxies point to the same Azure function but I don't get the proxy url as part of the request information

As a workaround I can have a separate Azure function for each http Url but this seems a little overkill.

Answer (score 1):

[Azure Function Proxies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-proxies) should be able to help you.

Lets say you have a azure function with the following URL
https://testfunctionproxies.azurewebsites.net/api/HttpTriggerCSharp1?name=alice

If you want this function to also be called with 
https://testfunctionproxies.azurewebsites.net/api/HttpTriggerCSharp1/home?name=alice

You can create a Proxy. This proxy will look something like this.
[image]

If you want to have other routes point to the same function, simply add more proxies.

Your proxies.json would look something like this

```
{
"proxies": {
    "proxy1": {
        "matchCondition": {
            "route": "/api/HttpTriggerCSharp1/home"
        },
        "backendUri": "https://testfunctionproxies.azurewebsites.net/api/HttpTriggerCSharp1"
    },
    "proxy2": {
        "matchCondition": {
            "route": "/home"
        },
        "backendUri": "https://testfunctionproxies.azurewebsites.net/api/HttpTriggerCSharp1"
    }
}
```

}

With this your function can now also be called as:
https://testfunctionproxies.azurewebsites.net/home?name=alice

If you need to identify the routes in your function, you could pass an query string parameter to you backend identify what was the original path.

```
{
   "$schema": "http://json.schemastore.org/proxies",
    "proxies": {
        "proxy1": {
            "matchCondition": {
                "route": "/api/HttpTriggerCSharp1/home"
            },
            "backendUri": "https://testfunctionproxies.azurewebsites.net/api/HttpTriggerCSharp1",
            "requestOverrides": {
                "backend.request.querystring.originalPath": "/api/HttpTriggerCSharp1/home"
            }
        },
        "proxy2": {
            "matchCondition": {
                "route": "/home"
            },
            "backendUri": "https://testfunctionproxies.azurewebsites.net/api/HttpTriggerCSharp1?origninalPath=home",
            "requestOverrides": {
                "backend.request.querystring.originalPath": "/home"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now if you call https://testfunctionproxies.azurewebsites.net/home?name=alice
will also give you the original path

Comment: that only partly gets me there. I don't see a way when my function method is called to see what route the request came in on.

Comment: that only partly gets me there. I don't see a way when my function method is called to see what route the request came in on. I handle/route differently in my function app based on if user requested /api/HttpTriggerCSharp1/home vs. /home. I don't see anything in the param passed to my function to indicate the path. The originalUrl in the context is alway set to the backendUri. Is there was a matchCondition property to check for?

Comment: route for proxies are similar to HttpTriggers. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-http-webhook#url) for more info on how to customize routes

Comment: @SquatchyCode If you need to handle routes differently in the function, then having two functions is not a bad idea, and you can have shared code pulled into a library. If you still need to identify the user requested route, then you could use an upcoming feature in Proxies that allows you to add a query string parameter before calling the backend, and you can check for this parameter in the function. I have updated the answer with the proxies.json in this case.

Comment: Thank you very much.  If instead the matchCondition or the original customer Url was just in the header or request context I could do a wild card match and would work for both the proxies.json and the route in my function.json.  side Note: why require an absolute path for the backendUri. If this could be a server relative Url  I don't have to edit the proxies.json for different deployments.

Comment: You could as well use `"backend.request.headers.originalPath": "/home"` to set the originalPath in the header. Proxies can point to external urls or functions from different function apps, hence BackendUri is absolute path. Note that you can use application settings in your backend Uri, this could be used to solve the issue of different deployments. Find more info in the documentation [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-proxies)

Comment: If you want to monitor your Function endpoints, you should use AppInsights which is fully integrated to the service now